# Rotating matrix of points for a custom angle

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication

I wanted to make matrix of points and rotate them for a custom angle.
I get a bunch of 0's when I enter the desired angle, can't figure out why.
Might be a pretty simple mistake, I'm kind of new to programming in C, trying to learn.

Here's my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
double pi = 3.14159265;
double rot[2][2], obj[2][10], obj2[2][10];
int a, c, d, i, j;
double x,y, sum=0;
double element = 0;

printf("Enter the number of columns of the matrix:\n");
scanf("%d", &a);

printf("Enter the elements of the matrix:\n");

for (c = 0; c < 2; c++){
    for (d = 0; d < a; d++){
        scanf("%lf", &obj[c][d]);
    }
}

printf("Enter the desired clockwise rotation angle:\n");
scanf("%lf", &x);
if ((int)x > 360){
    x = (int)x % 360;
}
if ((int)x < 0){
    x = 360 + x;
}

y = (pi / 180) * x;

rot[0][0] = cos(y);
rot[0][1] = sin(y);
rot[1][0] = -sin(y);
rot[1][1] = cos(y);


for (c = 0; c < 2; c++){
    for (d = 0; d < a; d++){
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            sum += rot[c][i] * obj[i][d];
        }
        obj2[c][d] = sum;
        sum = 0;
    }
}

printf("Rotated object in matrix form:\n");
for (c = 0; c < 2; c++){
    for (d = 0; d < a; d++){
        printf("%f\t", obj2[c][d]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Had a problem with accepting values into matrix fields, pretty much all values were messy. Also there was & in the printf function so it printed the wrong thing. All solved now, tweaked some outputs to look better but it's a functioning code now.

EDIT: After fixing the printf, I get http://prntscr.com/7fgq7m after the debug.
EDIT2: Entering values works properly, will now play with sin() and cos() part to see if that works aswell.

FINAL EDIT: Everything works smoothly for the values I planned, will do a lot more testing with friends, but this looks fine.
Thank you everyone that helped, much appreciated.

Comment: `printf("%.lf\t", &obj2[c][d]);` --> `printf("%.lf\t", obj2[c][d]);`

Comment: Oh, overseen that, thank you, I still get some error, but, progress

Comment: ... and you don't need `%lf` for a `double` in `printf`, you only need `%lf` for a `double` in `scanf`. It's just `printf("%f", [doublevalue])`

Comment: Fixed that too, didn't actually know that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scanf("%.lf", &obj[c][d]);
```

it is wrong. "%.lf" there is no such a specifier. It must be "%lf" for double type values.

Also you are using `fflush(stdin);` which is not right to flush standart input buffer and it is undefined behaviour according to standarts `(C11 7.21.5.2)`. (okey compilers supports it, but wrong).

You can use your own function something like that;

```
void FlushStdin(void)
{
     int ch;    
     while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF )
          ;
}
```

Comment: I'm not that certain about the fflush, I will try replacing it with such a function, all I know is that without it, it only takes the first element and goes further, so I get to enter only 1 element, which is not what I wanted.

Comment: @EternalEnvy there shouldn't be any problem with inputs. Whether they are separated by spaces or `newline` then `scanf` should filter that out (with numeric input). Did you remove the `.` from all the `scanf` statements?

Comment: Yes, I have, it just skips the rest of the for loops and goes out if I remove the fflush, at the very first scanf. EDIT: Works now for some reason, I don't even know

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.` from this line so it reads

```
scanf("%lf", &x);
```

which error would be revealed if you printed the input value.

Also, I see you are fumbling with checking the input value but `sin()` and `cos()` only fail with stupidly extreme inputs.

Another point, `fflush(stdin)` is implementation defined and isn't usually necessary.

**UPDATE** here is a bug

```
for (d = 0; d < a; c++)
```

which should be

```
for (d = 0; d < a; d++)
```

Comment: Removed the dot, still works fine.
My first time using the sin() and cos() functions, so I wasn't sure.
As to fflush, doesn't seem to work when I remove it.

Comment: With the dot, I entered 1.23 which was printed as 0.00000, without the dot is printed as 1.230000

Comment: I didn't test all the values yet, or the ifs, wanted to get it to work for easy values and then tweak it for the corner cases

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that was it, works without errors now, just getting silly values

Comment: I suggest removing the range checking for degrees for now in case it mis-manages the values. Enable it later when the code works.

Comment: Right, I'll do it that way, seems that writing the values to matrices doesn't work. Also, do you happen to know where should I put the printf("/t"); in order to get it to enter elements of matrices tabbed, so it visually represents a matrix, I tried few places but it was buggy.

Comment: Yes, better than `tab` is to use the field width specifier like `printf("%8f", [double])` which will right-justify in a field width of 8 in this case. There is quite a *lot* to format specifiers. You can even give the field width itself as an argument, see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25366k66.aspx

Comment: Well you cancelled your "accept" even though the other added nothing more, but I'll give you one more tip. Change `int sum` to `double sum`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did that too, I think I should update the code now, my bad.

Comment: OK, but altering the posted code makes all the previous comments look silly. Better to ask a new question with the revised code if necessary.

Comment: Should I then type what I changed from the original, I'm new here, terribly sorry.

Comment: You should clarify the problem. Is it something to do with skipping inputs, or incorrect outputs? What inputs are you giving, and what outputs are you expecting? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Quite often the approach I linked will solve your problem anyway. But first, deal with the input and make sure that works.